# Debezium CDC connector to EventHub

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-eventhub, debezium

I am trying to use Debezium CDC connector to send data from the SQL server to Azure EventHub. But table is not getting created in EventHub from the SQL server. I am not getting any error as well. All the defaults topics are created in eventhub when i started the connector

followed this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-kafka-connect-tutorial

and worked fine. Will CDC connector works fine with eventhub.. any idea?`

Comment: Has been a while, are you still running into this issue?

Comment: Did anyone figure out how to connect to event hubs using debezium?

Answer (score 0):

Debezium today only supports Kafka as out of box connector. If you need to write notifications to any other sink, you need to implement in embedded mode. See https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.0/operations/embedded.html